# android device's status offline sometime

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, device

I would like to ask a question I am facing now.
My eclipse cannot use my device as the debugger. However, I could do so yesterday.
This situation occurs sometimes and I want to figure out the reason.
Will it be related to the USB I am using?? Or the settings in my device??

[image: Device Status]

Comment: Check your USB debugging setting, try revoking the USB debugging authorization once, unplug then plug the USB/device. Try resetting the ADB (DDMS -> Devices -> Reset adb). I don't know if it will help, but I usually do this if that happens. If you have other device, try with that to test if you have problem with the USB.

Comment: Three days before i have same problem , in my case it was issue of USB port.Or you can do one thing take look on DEV setting.